# Unity registration by convention doesn't work unless you rebuild solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to use the Registration by Convention feature of Unity in a pretty standard MVC4 app.  I'm using the following code...

```
unityContainer.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),
  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
  WithName.Default,
  WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

Here's my problem.  If a rebuild is done on the solution, the registration works perfect.  If I go right back into debugging the app after I end it, not causing a build, the registration does not work.  It appears to add some registrations to the container, but not all.

Has anyone ran into a similar problem or have a solution to this one?  I'll provide any additional information that is needed, but I'm assuming this one will only be fixed by "I've seen this before" :)

Comment: Can this be caused by the edit and continue feature of Visual Studio? I've seen similar issues when debugging a WCF service that didn't shut down causing the service's initialization phase to be skipped. It is unlikely that the problem is related to Unity itself.